# What does binaries mean?

Tags: elixir

When I import an exs file that contains a function as follow:

```
iex(6)> import_file("mymath.exs")
{:module, MyMath,
 <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 4, 212, 66, 69, 65, 77, 69, 120, 68, 99, 0, 0, 0, 147, 131, 104, 2, 100, 0, 14, 101, 108, 105, 120, 105, 114, 95, 100, 111, 99, 115, 95, 118, 49, 108, 0, 0, 0, 4, 104, 2, ...>>,
 {:square, 1}}
```

What does binaries exactly represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once Elixir builds on top of Erlang to provide distributed and fault-tolerant,
this sequence of number <<70, 79, 82, 49, 0, 0, 4, .... ...>> represents your binary code who is running inside your Erlang VM (BEAM).

As a *real-life* example you can use it to make hot code deployments. How?
Using a rpc call with load binary, passing your binary code as arguments.

I.e

```
{_Module, Binary, Filename} = code:get_object_code(Module).
 rpc:call(Node, code, load_binary, [Module, Filename, Binary]).
```

Follow a really good article about how it works and how you can manipulate your bytecode between erlang nodes.
http://seanstavro.com/blog/elixir-slave-nodes/

Cheers,
@MC

Answer (score 1):

The numbers are the binary representation of the imported module.